# Raphael.js VSDOC

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, intellisense, raphael

Has anybody got a raphael.js vsdoc file (for visual studio 2010 intellisense support)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is now a vsdoc file for raphael.js

http://lobjs.wordpress.com/2012/02/02/raphael-vsdocs/

I've written it with the explicit intention of only using methods and properties documented in Raphael's documentation in the vsdoc file.  So you also won't see propertys which start with _ in intellisense if you use this.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you can generate using a VSDOC generator.

I found one at:

https://github.com/appendto/jquery-vsdoc/tree/master/Vsdoc%20Generator

Comment: this VSDOC generator is a parser for the api of jquery which is thankfully available as nicely structured XML (http://api.jquery.com/api). The only thing raphael offers is this page: http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html

Comment: If you add the raphael.js as a reference, Intellisense will give you autocompletion.